# What software can I use to link my public domain to my dynamically changing local computer IP?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, ip, localhost, dynamic

Any free websites/software that might be recommended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few, the most popular are DynDNS and no-ip.com.  If you want to integrate with your network and not install any software, see if your router or firewall natively supports dynamic DNS - most routers do these days.  Some vendors only support some of the dynamic DNS services, that could help you narrow down your choices as well.  With router integration, you just put in your account information and the router does all the work and updates the service when your IP changes - nothing to think about, nothing to install, which is always nice.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.dyndns.com/support/clients/windows.html

Answer (score 1):

Once you have setup dyndns, you then need to add a CNAME entry for your DNS server, for example:

1) Register stormist.dyndns.org and make sure it resolve to the IP address of your pc.

2) Then add a CNAME pc.stormist.come that points to stormist.dyndns.org ( the pc part of the domain can be anything you choose)